# Replace elements in list not matching elements of another list at the same position

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to compare two arrays:

```
m = {a,b,c,d,d,f};
n = {b,b,a,d,d,e};
```

and get:

```
{0,b,0,d,d,0}
```

I have tried all kinds of things, like:

```
m = {a,b,c,d,d,f};
n = {b,b,a,d,d,e};
Transpose[{m, n}];
If[{x_ == y_} :> x, 0]
```

but clearly, I have no idea what I am doing! I am (obviously) very new to *Mathematica*, and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Will the elements always be symbols, or will they sometimes be values, or characters/strings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following solution may look a bit weird, but has an advantage of automatically being very efficient for numerical large lists:

```
m * (1 - Block[{Unitize}, _Unitize = 1; #] & [ Unitize[m - n]])
```

Comment: +1. Are you still going to write that part 2 of your book? I know you're super busy, just curious.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks. Re: book - yes, I am going to, although it is not yet clear what the format of it will be, or set the exact time frame for it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Good to know. The first one is a classic by the way.

Comment: @RunnyKine Well, thanks :) I wrote it when I knew so much less than I do now (which I do in a big part due to this community), and I can see many flaws in the book now - so it's always good to know that it is not totally bad :)

Answer (score 10):

```
MapThread[If[SameQ[#1, #2], #1, 0] &, {m, n}]
```

or

```
Transpose[{m, n}] /. {p_, q_} :> If[SameQ[p, q], p, 0]
```

Comment: Many thanks, Chris!

Answer (score 8):

```
Inner[ If[ #1 === #2, #1, 0] &, m, n, List]
```

> ```
> {0, b, 0, d, d, 0}
> ```

or with `Transpose` and `Apply`:

```
If[#1 === #2, #1, 0] & @@@ Transpose[{m, n}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an unconventional way, which I think should be reasonably fast (thanks to Leonid for spotting a flaw):

```
Replace[m + n, _Plus -> 0, {1}] / 2
(* {0, b, 0, d, d, 0} *)
```

The idea is that `a + b` will have the head `Plus`, whereas `a + a` is `2 a`, which has the head `Times`. Needless to say, a severe drawback of this approach is when the elements of the lists are numbers...

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Oops... Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5):

And yet another variation using rules:

```
Thread@{m, n} /. {{p_, p_} :> p, {_, _} :> 0}
```

(Also `Thread` instead of `Transpose` for extra differenceness)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a straightforward approach quite similar to your first attempt, which has the feature that it will work for numbers as well as symbols.

```
m = {1, b, c, 5.0, d, f};
n = {3, b, a, 5.0, d, e};
Table[If[m[[i]] === n[[i]], m[[i]], 0], {i, Length[m]}]

{0, b, 0, 5., d, 0}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m (1 - Sign[Length /@ (m - n)])
(*{0, b, 0, d, d, 0}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**My solution:**

```
m * Boole@MapThread[SameQ, {m, n}]
```

> {0, b, 0, d, d, 0}

---

**And here's the comparison:**

```
m = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k}, 1000000];
n = RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k}, 1000000];

(*Leonid Shifrin*)
m*(1 - Block[{Unitize}, _Unitize = 1; #] &[Unitize[m - n]]); // AbsoluteTiming

(*Artes*)
Inner[If[#1 === #2, #1, 0] &, m, n, List]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*Artes*)
If[#1 === #2, #1, 0] & @@@ Transpose[{m, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*Chris Degnen*)
MapThread[If[SameQ[#1, #2], #1, 0] &, {m, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*Chris Degnen*)
Transpose[{m, n}] /. {p_, q_} :> If[SameQ[p, q], p, 0]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*rm-rf*)
Replace[m + n, _Plus -> 0, {1}]/2; // AbsoluteTiming(*rm-rf*)

(*wxffles*)
Thread@{m, n} /. {{p_, p_} :> p, {_, _} :> 0}; // AbsoluteTiming

(*chyaong*)
m (1 - Sign[Length /@ (m - n)]); // AbsoluteTiming

(*RunnyKine*)
n*Replace[m/n, {1 -> 1, _ -> 0}, {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*alephalpha*)
m * Boole@MapThread[SameQ, {m, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {5.359334, Null}
>   {1.688222, Null}
>   {1.920503, Null}
>   {1.629107, Null}
>   {2.132745, Null}
>   {1.964956, Null}
>   {1.396690, Null}
>   {3.478013, Null}
>   {3.582479, Null}
>   {1.933204, Null}

Comment: @Artes It refers to Loenid's one.

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from rm -rf here's one that should also work with numbers (If there are no zeros).

```
n * Replace[m / n, {1 -> 1, _ -> 0}, {1}]
```

> `{0, b, 0, d, d, 0}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```
m * (1 - Abs[MapThread[Order, {m, n}]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea of `sparseArray` can be pretty useful in case of large matrices or on extending it to multi-dimensional.

```
Block[{m = {a, b, c, d, d, f}, n = {b, b, a, d, d, e}, sep, 
  sum}, {sep = ArrayPad[#, {0, Length[m] - Length[#]}] & /@ 
    Flatten[Normal[SparseArray[{1, #} -> n[[#]]]] & /@ 
      Flatten[Position[Subtract[m, n], 0]], 1], 
  sum = ConstantArray[0, Length[m]]}; 
 Table[sum = sep[[i]] + sum, {i, Length[sep]}] // Last]
```

> {0, b, 0, d, d, 0}